# Mapbox iOS - Show multiple callouts

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox

I want to show multiple annotations at once in Mapbox (note: NOT MKMap). There doesn't seem to be a method to show multiple annotations, although it can add multiples.

e.g.

```
mapView.addAnnotations(<annotationsArray>)
```

Even though there is a method as follows, it does not show the annotations.

```
mapView.showAnnotations(<annotationsArray>, animated: true)
```

What I want it to show multiple instances as shown in the image below. i.e. I want to show several "Hello World" annotations in the map, for each point the user added.

[image]

Is there a similar method in Mapbox to show multiple annotations in Swift?

Comment: Do you want to get all annotations of map?

Comment: what do you want to achieve by selecting all annotations? Can you please also share it?

Comment: You can't select multiple annotations AFAIK.

Comment: @HardikS yes. I can share. In the map, there are places marked my user and when the map is loaded, I want to show all the places that the user has marked, at once.

Comment: @Curiousity means you want to get all the markers that are currently displaying on the map?

Comment: @HardikS yes. I've updated the question. Hope you can get a more clear picture about my problem

Comment: @HardikS I think I made a mistake when saying I want to "select" multiple annotations. I was think along the method and used the same wording. What I actually want is to "show" the annotation at once for multiple points

Comment: @Curiousity You can't show all the annotations as you showed in the image. To achieve it,  you can create custom annotations and show it for only those annotations which are selected.

Comment: The red thing is an annotation. The white thing with "Hello world!" is a callout. Which do you want to show all of, at the same time? You can show multiple annotations - it is very easy. You cannot show multiple callouts at the same time.

Comment: @Magnas yes. What I want to show multiple times are callouts. So there is not workaround for that either? :(

Comment: @Curiousity I guess you would need to iterate through each annotation in the annotations array and access the frame of each one and then add and position your custom view (your own callout) based on that. When an actual Mapbox callout is showing it denotes that annotation is selected, which is why only one at a time is possible with the api.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to display multiple annotations:

```
func setAnnotations() {
        var index = 0
        for placeModel in self.placesList! {
            let marker = MyMGLPointAnnotation()
            marker.willUseImage = true
            marker.id = placeModel.id
            marker.type = placeModel.type
            if let img = placeModel.images.first {
                marker.imgURL = img.thumbnail
            }
            marker.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: placeModel.location?.latitude ?? 0, longitude: placeModel.location?.longitude ?? 0)
            marker.title = placeModel.name.withoutHtmlTags
            marker.subtitle = placeModel.descr.htmlToString

            //DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.mapView.setCenter(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude), zoomLevel: 12, animated: false)

                self.mapView.addAnnotation(marker)
        }
    }
```

You can display multiple instance of the annotations but for the selection you can tap one by one and it will show title like the image you shared.

**Edit:** There is way you can create your custom xib load as annotation to show the title.

Check: https://github.com/mapbox/ios-sdk-examples/blob/0e2c8ce878de500f36c4168f7a1e62041c8adbdf/Examples/Swift/AnnotationViewsAndImagesExample.swift

https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/maps/examples/annotation-view-image/